# Racket - How to count the number of elements in a list?

Tags: racket

I was wondering how to count the number of elements
For example, counting the number of elements in (list 'a 'b 'c' 'd).  Thank you!

Answer (score 6):

Based on racket documentation :

[http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def.*%28%28quote.*~23~25kernel%29._length%29%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._length%29%29)

(length lst)
Returns the number of elements in lst.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do see how you can do it yourself recursively, one way to do it is this:

```
(define (my-length lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      0
      (+ 1 (my-length (rest lst)))))
```